# Logging of ROS_ERROR_STREAM messages?

Tags: ros, c++, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I log ROS_ERROR_STREAM messages into a log file??

Normally i would just do a >> log.txt but, i only want to store the ROS_ERROR_STREAM, and nothing else..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234319/logging-of-ros_error_stream-messages?/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2016-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ros logging macros ([rosconsole](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole)) use log4cxx and are compatible with log4j configuration files.

It's probably possible to write a configuration file that does what you want, but the documentation is pretty thin: http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/usage.html

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might not be the best way to do this, but this is what comes to my mind:

```
$ rosrun sample_pkg sample_node 2>&1 | grep -e "\[ERROR\]" -e "\[FATAL\"] > /path/to/file
```

Alternatively, you can pipe all messages written to `stderr` to a file. This includes all ROS `WARN`, `ERROR` and `FATAL` messages: ([ref](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging#Output))

```
$ rosrun sample_pkg sample_node 2>/path/to/file
```

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1